# Time scale of standard deviation of stochastic asset prices

Tags: stochastic-processes, price, standard-deviation

If I run a stochastic interest rate model that is used to price a bond that is a series of cash flows under $N$ scenarios where the price is the average of all the scenarios, $P = \sum_{n=1}^N p_n / N$, can I infer a time scale for the standard deviation (vol) of the stochastic prices?

For more detail, the interest rate model provides a set of discount-factors for each scenario $df_{t,n}$ and the asset is a series of cash flows $cf_t$ that is priced as $p_n = \sum_{t=1}^T cf_t df_{t,n}$.

I cannot think of why I would justifiably say "this is an annualized standard deviation" over "this is a daily standard deviation".

Should I be using the WAL of the cash flows as the time scale?  Or the time horizon $T$?

Update:  I added a bounty to get more attention.  At its core, this question is essentially asking:  What can I infer about the standard deviation of the stochastically generated asset prices $p_n$?

Comment: I don't work in this sort of thing but it would make sense to me if the units of $t$ were the same as the units of the cash flows. So, if the cash flows are monthly, then let $\Delta t$ be a month. or if the cash flows are daily, let $\Delta t$ be a day etc.

Comment: Also, generally, standard deviation or variance is calculated using the returns. It can be converted to a standard deviation of the log prices ( if one makes enough assumptions ) but, generally speaking,  when people talk about volatility, they are referring to that of the returns.

Comment: Why do you want there to be a time associated with the uncertainty?

Comment: @Arshdeep I would like to know the vol of the asset price $P$ for e.g. one day.  I do not know the time scale of the standard deviation, so I don't know how to convert to one-day vol, i.e. $\sigma_{day} = \sigma_{year}\sqrt{252}$

Comment: "vol of the price" doesn't exist, price is not stationary. Uncertainty in the price exists, which is computational uncertainty. What do you intend to do once you "know the time scale"?

Comment: I think you need to model daily log returns of the price, characterize standard deviation of that. Then you can convert it as you say. As of now you have computational uncertainty, you can't use that as vol.

Comment: @Arshdeep I want to know the expected standard deviation of the price at e.g. 30 days from now.  So are you suggesting that I would run the interest rate model to thirty days and observe the price distribution at that time period?

Comment: Say bond expires in 30 days. Then price is always one and has 0 variation. You have to price the thing in the future. And then take stdevn of that.